# List View \ Database \ ComboBox , c#

Tags: c#, sql, listview

On my form there is 6 Combo-Boxes. I have stored their values in a table "TableauCombo" to use again. I set a "for" to browse the table and for each step, the program has to write in the variable "query" all the values that are in the table. ( To create the SQL query). Next, I launch the SQL Request and have to write the values in the list view. I have some errors, but I'm unable to resolve them. Can you help me?

I put the code and the errors underneath

```
 string[] TableauCombo = new string[7];
                {
                    TableauCombo[0] = "ID_Rad=@" + CatégorieRadiologique_ComboBox_Home.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                    TableauCombo[1] = "Code_Etat=@" + CodeEtatFS_ComboBox_Home.SelectedIndex.ToString(); ;
                    TableauCombo[2] = "Code_Producteur=@" + Producteur_ComboBox_Home.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                    TableauCombo[3] = "Code_Centre=@" + Centre_ComboBox_Home.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                    TableauCombo[4] = "Code_StationdeDestination=@" + StationDestination_ComboBox_Home.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                    TableauCombo[5] = "Code_Conditionnement=@" + Conditionnement_ComboBox_Home.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                };

                string requery = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < TableauCombo.Length; i++)
                {
                    requery = requery + TableauCombo[i];
                }
                LW_FS_Home.Items.Clear();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT FS FROM cdh.fiche WHERE " + requery + " ", connection);            // Requète SQL SELECT 
                MessageBox.Show("Requery" + requery + "");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Rad", CatégorieRadiologique_ComboBox_Home.SelectedIndex.ToString());          //Récupération du ID_Rad souhaité par l'utilisateur
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code_Etat", CodeEtatFS_ComboBox_Home.ToString());                                //Récupération du Code_Etat souhaité par l'utilisateur
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code_Producteur", Producteur_ComboBox_Home.ToString());                          //Récupération du Code_Producteur souhaité par l'utilisateur
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code_Centre", Centre_ComboBox_Home.ToString());                                  //Récupération du Code_Centre souhaité par l'utilisateur
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code_StationdeDestination", StationDestination_ComboBox_Home.ToString());        //Récupération du Code_StationdeDestination souhaité par l'utilisateur
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code_Conditionnement", Conditionnement_ComboBox_Home.Text);                      //Récupération du Code_Conditionnement souhaité par l'utilisateur

                if (Connecté)
                {
                    using (MySqlDataReader Lire = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (Lire.Read())  // Boucle While qui regarde toutes les infos que l'on souhaite voir avec la méthode "lire"
                        {
                            string FS = Lire["@FS"].ToString();                                                               // Declaration des colonnes et leurs équivalents (remplacants)
                            string ID_Rad = Lire["@ID_Rad"].ToString();
                            string Code_Etat = Lire["@Code_Etat"].ToString();
                            string Code_Producteur = Lire["@Code_Producteur"].ToString();
                            string Code_Centre = Lire["@Code_Centre"].ToString();
                            string Code_StationdeDestination = Lire["@Code_StationdeDestination"].ToString();
                            string Code_Conditionnement = Lire["@Code_Conditionnement"].ToString();

                            LW_FS_Home.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { FS, ID_Rad, Code_Etat, Code_Producteur, Code_Centre, Code_StationdeDestination, Code_Conditionnement }));// Ajout des nouvelles valeurs dans la list view
                        }
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Erreur de connexion");
                }
}
```

The error :

> "MySqlException : Parameter '@1' must be defined."

But the program can run itself. (Comment : test for the end) The value who is returned is : "RequeryID_Rad=@1+..........". (Picture) [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkTXl.png)

Just to be explicit, all combobox has declared like that :

```
try //Début Try/Catch pour le ComboBox des catégorie Radiologiqque
{
    connection.Open();
    CatégorieRadiologique_ComboBox_Home.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList; //ReadOnly sur la comboBox
    string selectQuery = "SELECT ID_Rad , Radiologique FROM cdh.ctg_rad";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read()) {
        CatégorieRadiologique_ComboBox_Home.Items.Add(reader.GetString("Radiologique"));
        string[, ] TableauRad = new string[1, 2] {
            {
                "ID_Rad", "Radiologique"
            },

        };
    }
    connection.Close();
} catch (MySqlException cn)

{
    MessageBox.Show(cn.Message);
    connection.Close();
}
```

I think my "for" it's wrong or the link with the listview idk..

Comment: you should try to write better question titles. "ListView's Parameters" is extremely ambiguous and does not really relate to your problem at all

Comment: Sorry , i'll change it

Answer (score 0):

You passed the parameter wrongly, you should pass just parameter name in query and set parameter with `command.Parameters.Add` like below:

```
string[] TableauCombo = new string[6];
TableauCombo[0] = "ID_Rad=@ID_Rad";
TableauCombo[1] = "Code_Etat=@Code_Etat";
TableauCombo[2] = "Code_Producteur=@Code_Producteur";
TableauCombo[3] = "Code_Centre=@Code_Centre";
TableauCombo[4] = "Code_StationdeDestination=@Code_StationdeDestination";
TableauCombo[5] = "Code_Conditionnement=@Code_Conditionnement";

string requery = string.Join(" AND ", TableauCombo);
LW_FS_Home.Items.Clear();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT FS FROM cdh.fiche WHERE " + requery + " ", connection);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Rad", CatégorieRadiologique_ComboBox_Home.SelectedIndex.ToString());          //Récupération du ID_Rad souhaité par l'utilisateur
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code_Etat", CodeEtatFS_ComboBox_Home.SelectedIndex.ToString());                                //Récupération du Code_Etat souhaité par l'utilisateur
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code_Producteur", Producteur_ComboBox_Home.SelectedIndex.ToString());                          //Récupération du Code_Producteur souhaité par l'utilisateur
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code_Centre", Centre_ComboBox_Home.SelectedIndex.ToString());                                  //Récupération du Code_Centre souhaité par l'utilisateur
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code_StationdeDestination", StationDestination_ComboBox_Home.SelectedIndex.ToString());        //Récupération du Code_StationdeDestination souhaité par l'utilisateur
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code_Conditionnement", Conditionnement_ComboBox_Home.SelectedIndex.ToString());                      //Récupération du Code_Conditionnement souhaité par l'utilisateur
```

but I'm not sure about combo box selected indices that as the same as column values in **cdh.fiche** table

Comment: The problem is that requery will be in an SQL query, so I can’t place my "@..." in my array. Otherwise they will be in my query and my database does not know this information. It can only read the "ID,CODE" elements.

Comment: this the way how you pass parameter to sql command to prevent sql injection, What do you mean database does not know about this information?

Comment: Nothing , I did'nt really understood what you has tring to say. Check that, I improved the code , the sql's request is better but i didn't used your part about the array , but I used "string.join.." + some update...

Comment: you have problem with writing query with parameters and passing them afterward, look at this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Ok I'll see that

Answer (score 0):

Please replace code to

```
string[] TableauCombo = new string[6];
            {
                TableauCombo[0] = "ID_Rad=@ID_Rad";
                TableauCombo[1] = "Code_Etat=@Code_Etat";
                TableauCombo[2] = "Code_Producteur=@Code_Producteur";
                TableauCombo[3] = "Code_Centre=@Code_Centre";
                TableauCombo[4] = "Code_StationdeDestination=@Code_StationdeDestination";
                TableauCombo[5] = "Code_Conditionnement=@Code_Conditionnement";
            };
```

Comment: Yes, check at the top , I added some screenshots

Comment: Also please change the line by                                                                                   
       string requery = string.Join(" AND ", TableauCombo);                                                                           And please don't use                                                                                                                 
                   for (int i = 0; i < TableauCombo.Length; i++)
                    {   
                        requery = requery + TableauCombo[i];
                    }